# Set<String> doesn't maintain order the same as the order the elements were added in

Tags: java, set, setstring

**Edit**: this is actually for an Android application, which means (as far as I know), I can only use a HashSet.

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();

set.add("1");
set.add("2");
set.add("3");
set.add("4");
set.add("5");
set.add("6");
set.add("7");
set.add("8");

String[] array = set.toArray(new String[0]); // convert the set to an array

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array)); // test what the set looks like
```

---

The output of that is `[3, 2, 1, 7, 6, 5, 4, 8]`

I expected `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]` because I assumed it would add the Strings to the Set in order of when I added them.

In my application, it's essential that the order of the Set is in the order that the elements were added to the Set.

Is there any reason that this Set is out of order? Or is there a way to put it back into the order that the elements were added in?

Comment: Take look at [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a `LinkedHashSet` if you want to order the elements of the set. For more details, see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) link.

Comment: I'm not sure that I can because this is actually for a SharedPreference in Android.

Comment: @mikeyaworski I don't think that matters. You could take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Set.html. It clearly specifies LinkedHashSet as one of the sub-classes.

Comment: Android can use a LinkedHashSet, but SharedPreferences can't store a LinkedHashSet. However, you did answer the question. This wasn't supposed to be about Android.

Answer (score 8):

Hlo.

1. HashSet - doesn't maintains insertion order.
2. LinkedHashSet - Maintains insertion order.
3. TreeSet - Keeping data in natural order or you can define custom order and pass the comparator.

You can go with second option.

```
Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
```

Comment: Karthikeyan, I hope you don't mind my editing. Just made it a little more specific.

Answer (score 3):

The data structure `HashSet` is unordered and unsorted collection. 
If you want your elements to be sorted using natural order, you can use [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)
If you want to maintain using insertion order, use [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html)

Answer (score 2):

No it's by design. A `HashSet` will insert your strings in buckets appropriate for your data, in a way that minimises the retrieval speed.

If you want to preserve lexographic order then use a `TreeSet`. (With the example you give that *would* work but only because your input data are sorted).

If you want to preserve insertion order then use a `LinkedHashSet`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a reason and you would have known if you read the first lines of it's javadoc:

> This class implements the Set interface, backed by a hash table (actually a HashMap instance). It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

Answer (score 1):

The`HashSet` doesn't maintain a predictable order, it will depend on the `hashCode` of the object reference. If you would like to maintain the order in which the elements are inserted, use a `LinkedHashSet`. If you want to maintain the elements always sorted, use a `TreeSet`.